# How to empty a wallet after the London Upgrade?

Tags: gas, eip-1559

Is it possible to empty an account after the London upgrade and if yes, how?

If I understand it correctly, I have to pay BaseFee + FeeTip and I know that a simple TX would consume exactly 21000 Gas. The documentation ([Gas](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/), [Transaction](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/transactions/)) tells me, that the TX input allows the fields `maxPriorityFeePerGas` and `maxFeePerGas`:

*maxPriorityFeePerGas - the maximum price of the consumed gas to be included as a tip to the validator*

*maxFeePerGas - the maximum fee per unit of gas willing to be paid for the transaction (inclusive of baseFeePerGas and maxPriorityFeePerGas)*

Assuming that I can predict the BaseFee of the next block, I should be able to set `baseFeePerGas` (which should work as an input instead of `maxFeePerGas`) exactly. Also, assuming that the the full FeeTip gets consumed by the miner, the TX to empty the account looks like this:

Fee: (PredictedBaseFee + HighTip) * 21000
TX value: Balance - Fee

Question is, is there any refund that gets send back to the sender account?

I am happy for any help, especially source code that validates any theory about this.